# ClassNotFoundException: demo.A || Even though the class name is package-qualified

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I have a file DA that analyzes various aspects of a package. (The name of folder that consists of the file to be analyzed, is always same as that of the package name)

```
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;    
public class DA {
        ArrayList<Class> classes;


        int numberOfClasses;
        String packageName;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            DA fl = new DA();
                fl.loadPackage(args[0]);
                fl.table();
        }

        public void loadPackage(String path) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

            Set<Class> set = new HashSet<Class>();
            System.out.println("Gathering class files in " + path);    

            FilenameFilter classFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".class");
                }
            };


            String className;

            File f = new File(path); // the directory, really!
            int n = 0;

            for (File file : f.listFiles(classFilter)){
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                this.packageName =  f.getName().toLowerCase();

                className = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length()-6);
                System.out.println(packageName + "." +className);
                Class<?> cl = Class.forName(packageName + "." +className);
                set.add(cl);
                n++;
            }

            this.classes = new ArrayList<Class>(set);
            this.numberOfClasses = n;
        }
```

For testing, I am setting class path to DA.jar and using a demo.java file that has a package named "demo". There are classes A,B,C,D,E, and F in the the package.

These are the things I am doing in the command line and I get the following error with the proper class name "demo.A" which really is the qualified class name.

Demo.java

```
package demo;


class A {
    public void meth1() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth1");
    }

    public void meth2() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth2");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void meth1() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth1");
    }

    public void meth2() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth2");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public void meth1() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth1");
    }

    public void meth2() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth2");
    }

    public void meth3() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth3");
    }

    public void meth4() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth4");
    }
}

class D {
    private B b = new B();
    public void meth1() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth1");
    }
}

class E {
    public void meth1(D d, A a) {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth1");
    }

    public void meth2() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth2");
    }
}

class F {
    private D d = new D();
    public void meth1(E e) {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth1");
    }

    public void meth2() {
        System.out.println("calling " + getClass() + ".meth2");
    }
}


public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.meth1();
        a.meth2();
        B b = new B();
        b.meth1();
        b.meth2();
        // etc.
    }
}
```

[Command Line Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCa1C.jpg)

I was running this program through eclipse earlier. I had a project called "Demo" which I added to the classpath in Run Configuration. And I also fed the argument to the folder that consisted of Demo.java and all .class files through Argument in Run Configuration. Could the reason be that my .class files and Demo.java were in separate addresses? (demo.java in src folder of eclipse project. And all .class and a copy of demo.java in desktop\demo)

Comment: Just because the file is there doesn't mean it's on the classpath. Run your java program with the contents of the directory in the classpath.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! I see the problem. I am getting error "Could not find or load main class demo.java"

Comment: I dont know why the demo.java wont run but I also tried running the jar by cd'ing to the class path and feeding demo's path as an argument. It gave me the same error of ClassNotFoundException: demo.A